# Frame around signature sometimes overshadows the text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I have seen this:

[image]

There's a frame around some users' (I didn't find why just some) name in their signature, and part of the text is hidden behind this frame.

Comment: I noticed this too. I thought it was only on suspended accounts. But I dont think SSumner is suspended.

Comment: @fredsbend - I'm definitely not :)

Answer (score 4):

I increased the line height for the comment text. The change is currently on our dev server, it will be on live within 24 hours.

Comment: Why is the background only on some names? What does it indicate?

Comment: @fredsbend: It indicates that the person is the original poster of the question and shows up in comments the OP leaves on that question and/or its answers.